# Триггер mysql как сделать чтобы реагировал на значение полей

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица:

```
Create table some_table(
date_to datetime, 
is_lost boolean default false
)
```

Как сделать такой тригер, который, при наступлении времени date_to менял бы значение поля is_lost в true?
Как бы такая фоновая служба
Или триггеры в mysql только по событиям срабатывают?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Триггеры для этого не предназначены. Тут надо использовать работу с запланированными событиями MySQL. Посмотрите пособие небольшое тут: [Работа с запланированными событиями MySQL](https://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/rabota-s-zaplanirovannymi-sobytiyami-mysql.html)